# variable from html to mysql and back to html not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, mysqli

I'm trying to pass a variable from my HTML page via CODE1 to CODE2 and get the output in my browser (HTML page). I'm getting the below error. What's the cause and how can I fix this?

ERROR:  
 **Warning**: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in **/home/abc/abc/ajax/test.php** on line **3**

HTML

```
<body>
Name: <input type="text" id="thename">
<input type="submit" id="thename-submit" value="GRAB">
<div id="thename-data"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/global.js"></script>
</body>
```

CODE1

```
$('input#thename-submit').on('click', function(){
    var ajaxname = $('input#thename').val();

    if ($.trim(ajaxname)!=''){ //if string is empty --- trim is to remove spaces only
        $.post('ajax/name.php', {thename:ajaxname}, function(data){
            $('div#thename-data').text(data);
        }); 
    }
});
```

CODE2

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['thename']) === true && empty($_POST['thename']) === false) {
    $getVal = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn_db, trim($_POST['thename']));
    require '../db/connection.php';
    $query = ("SELECT `photos`.`theurl` FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`thename` = '" . $getVal . "'") or die(mysqli_error($conn_db));
    $result = mysqli_query($conn_db, $query);

    $queryA = ("SELECT id FROM photos");
    $resultA = mysqli_query($conn_db, $queryA);
    $row_cnt = $resultA->num_rows;

    echo ($row_cnt !== 0 ? mysqli_result($result, '0', 'theurl') : 'Not found.'); // syntax meaning::  echo condition ? if TRUE output : if FALSE output;
} 

function mysqli_result($result, $ro, $field) { 
    $result->data_seek($ro); 
    $datarow = $result->fetch_array(); 
    return $datarow[$field]; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order of these two line:

```
$getVal = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn_db, trim($_POST['thename']));
require '../db/connection.php';
```

I assume `connection.php` assigns `$conn_db`.

Comment: Why would you think an error message about the `$conn_db` parameter would have anything to do with passing variables from HTML?

Comment: most of the answers here only mentioned to change the order of the line. but only your answer showed the other possibility also of getting the error i.e if $conn_db is not defined on connection.php file.. this is a good one..

Comment: @Barmar: Any idea why I'm not getting the 'Not found.' result when no results are found?

Comment: You're setting `$result` from the first query, but `$row_cnt` from the second one.

Comment: @Barmar: I missed your comment. I was not sure where the error was - so inorder to get the best and quicket answer I had to put all what was going on so an expert would spot the error and also even something more than just the error... got the point?

Comment: But your title implies that you didn't bother to read the error message.

Comment: it's been a looong days work Mr.Barmer... little things are huge to me right now... :) got it?  but I'm glad gus like you and the technology is there to help people like me...

Answer (score 0):

You should swap this line

```
$getVal = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn_db, trim($_POST['thename']));
require '../db/connection.php';
```

to

```
require '../db/connection.php';
$getVal = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn_db, trim($_POST['thename']));
```